# Video not run in Firefox

Tags: html, css, youtube

Please find the link below, I have embed the youtube video in header part, it runs in Chrome, IE9, but not in Firefox

http://demo.rimits.com/rpl/index.html

Can you please help on this ??

Regards
B

Comment: please provide the code?

Comment: No Flash Plugin installed in FF? ;) Chrome has its plugin builtin and IE uses a seperate one than FF I guess :)

Comment: You need Flash installed, Firefox (and many other browsers like Opera and IE) does not come as Chrome with built-in plugin.

Comment: Your code is good. do you installed video codec in mozilla? or is your mozilla is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened the link in Firefox 15 and it plays ok :-?